# What can cause UIScrollView to lose part of scrollview delegate?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a scrollview that acts weirdly. It scrolls very "insensitively", without the acceleration and deceleration, without the bounces working as well. What could be some of the reasons for this to be happening?

I am suspecting that it has something to do with the video recording I was trying to do. This problem seems only occur after I tried to take a video with AVFoundation...

As I have more than 1 scrollview using the same delegate, the following are the codes for my delegates...

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        //switch if reachs halfway
        CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor ((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2) / pageWidth) +1;
        if(self.pageControl.currentPage != page){
            [self performSelector:@selector(switchingTitle)];
            NSLog(@"scroll to change view");
        }
        NSLog(@"scrollviewdidscroll.");
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }

    -(void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        NSLog(@"scrollviewwillbegindragging");
    }

    -(void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
        if(decelerate == NO){
             NSLog(@"no deceleration.");
        }
        NSLog(@"scrollviewdidenddragging");
    }

    -(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        [self.content setDecelerationRate:UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal];
        NSLog(@"scrollviewwillbegindecelerating %f", self.content.decelerationRate);
    }

    -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        NSLog(@"scrollviewdidenddeceleration");
    }
```

The following is how the printout looks like when I do a drag... it will sort of repeat this pattern when I try to drag again.

```
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.503  scrollviewwillbegindragging
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.507  scrollviewdidscroll.
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.536  scrollviewdidscroll.
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.560  scrollviewdidscroll.
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.565  scrollviewdidscroll.
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.580  scrollviewdidenddragging
    2011-10-25 13:03:45.582  scrollviewwillbegindecelerating 0.998000
```

Edit: Added my video recording codes below... not all are here but this is the main bulk that takes care of the video recording which i suspect is the reason why the scrollview has stopped working correctly

```
-(void) startPreview {
     //preview layer
    if(previewLayer){ previewLayer = nil; }
    previewLayer =  [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];  

    if( UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
        self.previewLayer.orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatepreview) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil]; 

    self.previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [imageView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer]; 
}


-(void) captureSession{ 
    NSLog(@"captureSession");
    videoCaptureCompleted = NO;
    if (interrupted) {
        interrupted = NO;
    }
    //capture session
    if([session isRunning]){
        [session stopRunning];
        NSLog(@"session stopRunning");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        session =nil;
    }

    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];

    [self startPreview];
    NSLog(@"start Preview");
    //capture device
    cameraDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];  

    //capture device input
    NSError *error=nil;  
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* cameraInputTemp = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:cameraDevice error:&error]; 
    self.cameraInput = [cameraInputTemp retain];
    [cameraInputTemp release];
    if(!self.cameraInput){
        NSLog(@"camera input not found");
        return;
    }

    movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMake(10, 1);
    movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];

    // Add the input and output  
    [session addInput:self.cameraInput];  

    if([session canAddOutput:movieFileOutput]){
        [session addOutput:movieFileOutput];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"session refuses to add output");
    }

    [session startRunning]; 

    [self performSelector:@selector(prepareToRecording:)  withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:takeCount] afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void) prepareToRecording{
        [cameraDevice unlockForConfiguration]; 
        NSError* lockingError;
        if([cameraDevice lockForConfiguration:&lockingError]){
            [cameraDevice setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
        }
        while(cameraDevice.adjustingFocus){
            [self performSelector:@selector(waitForFetch)];
        } 
        if (!cameraDevice.adjustingFocus){
            [self performSelector:@selector(startVideoRecording:) withObject:takeCt afterDelay:3.0];
        }
    }
}

 -(void)startRecording{
        [[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:URLForVideo recordingDelegate:self];
 }

-(void) stopRecording{
    videoCaptureCompleted = YES;
    while ([movieFileOutput isRecording]) {
        [self.movieFileOutput stopRecording];
        NSLog(@"movieFileOutput stopRecording");
        [self performSelector:@selector(waitForFetch)];
    }

    //unlock configuration of autofocusing only once
    [cameraDevice unlockForConfiguration];

    if(![movieFileOutput isRecording]){
        [session performSelector:@selector(stopRunning) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
}

-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)URLForVideo fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections{
    NSLog(@"start recording video");

}

-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput*) movieFileOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: (NSURL*)URLForVideo fromConnections:(NSArray*)connections error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"recorded video");
}

-(void) startVideoRecording{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    if(!timerOn){
        timerLabel.text = @"Recording is starting!";
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:takeCt repeats:YES];
    }
}
```

Any more help please?

Comment: I tried printing out what happened using some of the delegates. scrollViewWillBeginDragging, then scrollViewDidScroll (a couple of times), then scrollViewDidEndDragging (when user stopped dragging), followed by scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating. Then there's no more print for scrolling...scrollViewDidEndDecelerating print did not appear. Any help please?

Comment: Why not set the decelerationRate out of the delegate method? Ideally you should keep delegate methods functionality to the minimum for speed. What exactly is switching title doing?

Comment: sorry for forgetting to explain a bit.. switching title changes the text in a label...I added the part to set decelerationRate towards to end but it somehow made no difference. After scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating, with or without that line that sets decelerationRate, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating will not be printed, even in cases where "no deceleration" is not printed...

Comment: I've added how the print out looks like from the delegates when I do a drag...I hope it helps. Thanx debuggerman & chown :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have turned on/off certain functionalities (properties) of the scroll view either in the InterfaceBuilder or programatically.  To customize these feature properties (adjust for your needs):

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
scrollView.bounces = YES;
scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
```

More properties in the [`UIScrollView` Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).  You can adjust the `decelerationRate` to what you need as well.

Comment: I tried setting those as well. It still looks like it isn't working. Could it be because of multiple scrollviews having a single class as the delegate? Or could it be some memory issue? Are those possible reasons?

Comment: Would need to see some of the delegates code to tell for sure, but its possible.

Comment: The delegate codes are added to the question. Thank you so much for helping chown :)

Comment: I am suspecting that it has something to do with the video recording I was trying to do. This problem seems only occur after I tried to take a video with AVFoundation...

Answer (score 0):

If you tap-drag the scrollview precisely, these functions will not be called (decelerate). DidScroll however will be called. If you however, tap-drag-release quickly (in a flick motion), then scroll view call `will begin/end decelerating` in a regular fashion. Its hard to do the flick in a simulator for some people. Try it on a device.

Comment: Hmm..but what confused me is that the delegate "scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating" was called... I've tried it on a device, but it gave me the same effect...